# excel concatenate IF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have what I think is a simple formula, but I am having trouble figuring it out:

Basically I want to specify if cell J2 = CAR or PANDA or CALAN then  CONCATENATE(B2,F2,J2,K2)  else
CONCATENATE(C2,F2,J2,K2)

I have tried and failed using countif and other expression types.  I feel I am overthinking this but looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you want

```
=if(or(j2="car",j2="panda",j2="calan"),CONCATENATE(B2,F2,J2,K2), CONCATENATE(C2,F2,J2,K2))
```

If (logical test, result if true, result if false).

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(OR(J2={"car","panda","calan"})+1,C2,B2),F2,J2,K2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you want to concatenate F2, J2 and K2, but you still need to decide if the whole thing needs to start with B2 or C2. You can do this as follows:

```
=IF(OR(J2="CAR";J2="PANDA";J2="CALAN");B2;C2) & F2 & J2 & K2
```